# Random number php not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to generate random number with [New York Lottery's Take 5](http://www.lotteryusa.com/lottery/NY/NYtake5_f10.html), it generates right, but then i wanted to write it to .txt file and then load it with ajax.

HTML:

```
    <div class="col-lg-10" id="rolled"></div>

    <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">
       <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
```

PHP:

```
function roll() {
        $server_seed = "39b7d32fcb743c244c569a56d6de4dc27577d6277d6cf155bdcba6d05befcb34";
        $lotto = "0422262831";
        $round_id = "1";
        $hash = hash("sha256",$server_seed."-".$lotto."-".$round_id);
        $roll = hexdec(substr($hash,0,8)) % 15;
        $fn = "ram.txt";
        $file = fopen($fn, "w");
        fwrite($file, $roll);
        fclose($file);
        echo "<script>paste_rolled();</script>";
    }
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        roll();
    }
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function paste_rolled() {
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("rolled").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
                }
            };
            xhttp.open("GET", "ram.txt", true);
            xhttp.send();
        }
```

It doesn´t work, even doesn´t write number to .txt file and i don´t know why.
When i tried that lotery system in another file, it worked. Thank you for any help.

Comment: "When i tried that [lottery] system in another file, it worked." What do you mean? the PHP or the JS? Or the output text file?

Comment: i meant PHP, but i tried only lottery system, not writing to file. It gave me random number.